# In C: How to print function argument

Tags: c

I want to print function argument in the printf command. Please help to suggest.

```
void printline(char ch, int len);
value(float, float, int);

main()
{
    double amount;
    printline('=', 30);
    amount = value(500, 0.12, 5); //  I want to print argument of function value. please help
    printf("The total amount is: %f \n", amount);
    //printf("%f\t%f\t%d\t%f \n", 500, 0.12, 5, amount);
    printline('=', 30);
    _getch();
}

void printline(char ch, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%c", ch);
    printf("\n");
}

value(float p, float r, int n)
{
    int year;
    float sum;
    sum = p;
    year = 1;
    while (year <= 5)
    {
        sum = sum * (1 + r);
        year = year + 1;
    }
    return(sum);
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? And what do you want to print? `char`?,  sequence of `char`s? `string`?

Comment: @wdc, I am not getting any error. But it just prints like below: ==============================
-867922223097294223219899068414767047150339070896408162281702553844529119294822519725532256957678500245617959157159789058525573856385606984030656440815664727951563690288278971226895615479699005629460285898096640.000000  0.000000    0
0.000000
==============================

Comment: Please code in 21st Century C.  Implicit `int` in the function declaration and definition of `value()` is obsolete since C99.  Ditto with the implicit `int` return type for `main()`.

Comment: Also, please edit the output into the question where you can format it.  Also, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: This code is not valid in any standard (C89 does not allow `//` comments)

Answer (score 1):

In your `printline` function you only have one character as an argument. So there is no purpose in iterating through it. If you want to print a `string` or array of characters you want to use `char *` or `char[]` and iterate through it. So your function `printline` could look like this:

```
void printline(char *ch, int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%c", ch[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

just make sure that `len` isn't bigger then the length of `*ch`.

Even better solution, where you don't have to worry about the value of `len` is to print the characters one by one until you come across the `\0` character indicating the end of an array.

```
 void printline(char *ch)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; ++i)
            printf("%c", ch[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Or [**even better**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53247075/in-c-how-to-print-function-argument#comment93379216_53247139)

> If the string is null terminated, use `printf("%s", ch)`. If the string is not null terminated but the length is supplied, use `printf("%.*s", len, ch)`. In both cases, there's no loop in the user code; the loop is buried inside the `printf()` function. Further, since there's a newline printed after the loops, use `printf("%s\n", ch)` or `printf("%.*s\n", len, ch)` and skip the extra `printf()` after the loop.

Comment: If the string is null terminated, use `printf("%s", ch)`.  If the string is not null terminated but the length is supplied, use `printf("%.*s", len, ch)`.  In both cases, there's no loop in the user code; the loop is buried inside the `printf()` function.  Further, since there's a newline printed after the loops, use `printf("%s\n", ch)` or `printf("%.*s\n", len, ch)` and skip the extra `printf()` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
value(500, 0.12, 5); //  I want to print argument of function value. please help
```

You can add a printf to the beginning of the function:

```
value(float p, float r, int n)
{
    printf("%s(%f, %f, %d)\n", __func__, f, r, n);
```